# C# Generic List conversion to Class implementing List<T>

Tags: c#, list, generics, linq-to-xml

The following code produces the issue

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<DataField<string>>'` to 'DataFields'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

How do I get around this? What am I doing wrong?

```
public class DataFields : List<DataField>
{
}

public abstract class DataField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataField<T> : DataField
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public static DataFields ConvertXML(XMLDocument data) {
    DataFields result = (from d in XDocument.Parse(data.OuterXML).Elements()
                      select new DataField<string>
                      {
                          Name = d.Name.ToString(),
                          Value = d.Value
                      }).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

**Edited:  Moving the information below to another question.**

[Using LINQ to create a List<T> where T : someClass<U>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170295/using-linq-to-create-a-listt-where-t-someclassu)

In addition I would like to be able to do something like the following in this statement, in order to set the type of the value for each. How can I accomplish this.

```
select new DataField<[Attribute of element called type]>
{
  Name = d.Name.ToString(),
  Value = d.Value
}
```

Comment: How, or why, would the compiler know to use `DataFields` as a result of the `ToList()` call? Why wouldn't it pick `DataFields2` (a subclass of `DataFields`) or `DataFields3` (an unrelated class that derives from `List<DataField<string>>`)?

Comment: To all.  OK clearly I have not thought this though, but it seems it should be possible.  Perhaps a different approach?  Im at a loss here and just looking for some Ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following constructor to the `DataFields` class

```
public class DataFields : List<DataField> {
    public DataFields() : base() {}
    public DataFields(IEnumerable<DataField> items) : base(items){}
}
```

Then

```
public static DataFields ConvertXML(XMLDocument data) {      
    var result = (BLAH..).ToList();      
    return new DataFields(result);     
}
```

Comment: @misha - it works for me, but I think it relies on Covariance of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, so only works for C#4 and later.

Comment: just call a Cast<DataField>() on the result before instantiating the new DataFields

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured out one way to handle this thanks to some insight from you guys

```
// Dont use this class
// public class DataFields : List<DataField>
// {
// }

public abstract class DataField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataField<T> : DataField
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public static List<DataField> ConvertXML(XMLDocument data) {  //return List<DataField>
     result = (from d in XDocument.Parse(data.OuterXML).Elements()
                      select new DataField<string>
                      {
                          Name = d.Name.ToString(),
                          Value = d.Value
                      }).Cast<DataField>().ToList();  // use cast
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you are trying to convert `DataField<T>` where `T` is `string` to `DataFields` which inherits from `List` of `Datafield` and they are not same.

So

`DataField<string>`  not equals `DataFields`, you could make your `DataFields` as a list of `string`s if you wanted this to work `DataFields : List<string>`

Comment: I've marked up the class names as code sequences, using backticks (`). This is especially important, since otherwise generics are treated as html tags, and your sentences don't make much sense when the generic portions are removed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

```
 public static DataFields ConvertXML(XmlDocument data)
        {
            DataFields result = (DataFields)(from d in XDocument.Parse(data.OuterXml).Elements()
                                  select new DataField<string>
                                  {
                                      Name = d.Name.ToString(),
                                      Value = d.Value
                                  }).Cast<DataField>();
            return result;
        }
```

We know that each element is `DataField` so we could cast it to that type.

Comment: No it is not a compile time error.   Yes It compiles for me, but it will not run.